# How to get data attribute of <select> for use in select2 from inside .select2() ajax call?

Tags: jquery-select2

I need to know what  element my select2 UI is based on so that I can grab data from a data-attribute. Maybe I'm missing it in the docs, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it.

Here is the basics of how my code is set up:

```
<form>
  <!--SNIP-->
  <select class="select-records" data-index=0>
    <option>Choose some records</option>
  </select>
  <!--SNIP-->
</form>

<script>
  $('.select-records').select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "/ajax/records",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: function (params) {
        // Need to get the data-index of the base <select> to process/pass along more info here
        return {
          q: params.term,
          page: params.page
        }
      },
      processResults: function(data, page) {
        return {
          results: data.items
        }
      },
      cache: true
    },
    minimumInputLength: 3
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, I need to access the data attribute (or id) inside the function that defines the params to sent with the ajax request.

Comment: Care to share your code and attempt(s)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I can't find anything that would tell me what to attempt. The code is really quite basic, at least in terms of what is directly related to getting the information. Here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/Gremlyn/75cdd1a3aa6457efe477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you want to add to your ajax query ...&ui=select1 for your select element.

1. Define your select in the following way: `<select data-ajax--id='select1' class="select-records" data-index=0>`
2. Your ajax's data function should now be:

   function (params) {
     return {
       q: params.term,
       ui: this.id,
       page: params.page
    }
   }

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like it should do the trick. I'll try it out tomorrow and choose your answer once I confirm. My reading of the docs made it sound like this would only work for existing select2 options, not ones I could make up on the fly.

Comment: Just a heads up, there will be a breaking change (bugfix) in 4.0.1 that will change `this` to reference the current element. It's [ticket 3361](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3361) on GitHub.

Comment: @KevinBrown - so if i read it right `this` will reference the `<select>` that the UI is based on, and not the ajax object? If so, I could have direct access to the data properties I add to my `<select>`, which is what I tried to do initially.

Comment: @TheGremlyn Correct, that'll be allowed in 4.0.1. For now you're going to have to settle with a hack like this when using 4.0.0.

Comment: Wish I could upvote more. This saved my day. I was tearing my hair out! Thank you!