# Select2 get html data attribute

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using latest select2 version.

But stuck at getting `<select>` html attribute.

```
<select name="category" id="category-select"
    data-ajax--search="slug" class="select2 form-control m-b-2" multiple>
</select>

// SCRIPT 

const opts = {
    ajax: {
        url: "/menus/search",
        delay: 250,
        data: function (param) {
            return {q: param.term, page: param.page, category: $(this.element).data('search')};
        },
        processResults: ({data, total_count}, {page}) => {
            page = page || 1;

            return {
                results: data,
                pagination: {
                    more: (page * 30) < total_count
                }
            };
        },
        cache: true
    },
    scapeMarkup: markup => markup,
    templateResult: formatRepo,
    templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
};
$('.select2').select2(opts);
```

I followed this solution [How to get data attribute of <select> for use in select2 from inside .select2() ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32259070/how-to-get-data-attribute-of-select-for-use-in-select2-from-inside-select2) and here https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3361 but still no luck.

my `data-ajax--search` always `return undefined`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using **$(this).data('ajax-Search')** instead of $(this.element).data('search')