# Access select2 html data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I tried following this question but with no success: [Select2 get html data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849440/select2-get-html-data-attribute)

How to access the html properties of the data delivered in the processResults function in the referenced link? Could someone provide a working example with the html data properties being available? Or give a short explanation into how/where to obtain these elements?

I would like to obtain the html elements during the processResults phase of the ajax call. In the referenced link the solution provided always return undefined. Also I would like to receive the HTML properties for the items sent through by the processResults function.

---

I will explain what I'd like to do. The items returned by the ajax call are grouped into categories. When one item is chosen from one category all other items in the same category become disabled. I would like to achieve this by obtaining the html properties of the items returned by the processResults function and disable them successively.

The code is fairly long so I will highlight the more relevant areas.

The html part looks as follows:

```
 <select class="form-control attributoSelect2" name="attributiSelezionati" id="attributoSelect2" value="@Model.AttributiSelezionati"></select>
```

Then I update this list using the following configuration:

```
$('.attributoSelect2').select2({
  placeholder: "Cerca Attributo",
  multiple: true,
  allowClear: true,
  minimumInputLength: 0,
  ajax: {
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 150,
    url: "@Url.Action(MVC.Configurazione.Attributi.CercaAttributi())",
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        search: params.term,
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data) {
      aaList = $(this).data('ajax-Search'); // this always returns undefined
      return {
        results: data.map(function(item) {
          return {
            id: item.GroupId,
            text: item.Descrizione,
            children: item.Children.map(function(itemC) {
              return {
                id: itemC.Id,
                groupid: itemC.GroupId,
                text: itemC.Descrizione,
              };
            })
          };
        })
      };
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2 get html data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42849440/select2-get-html-data-attribute)

Comment: In this link the data is processed in the data component of the ajax call. But I would like to obtain the elements received during the processResults component.

Comment: Put your code. so we can help you

Comment: I added a better explanation of what I'd like to do. Thank you for asking for more information.